# mysql optimise a query with inner join where and order by and co-ordinates

Tags: mysql, sql, join, sql-order-by, query-optimization

I'm just trying to get to grips with profiling.

I had a simply query optimised earlier but this one has a bit more involved so I'm not sure which columns I may need to add an index to in this case!

```
SELECT ReportID, Title, Description, postPic , DatePosted, UserID, FName, SName, authorNotificationId, userPic,  Lat, `Long`, 
photoWidth, photoHeight 
FROM 
(SELECT
        (((acos(sin((?*pi()/180)) 
        * sin((`Lat`*pi()/180))+cos((?*pi()/180))
        * cos((`Lat`*pi()/180)) * cos(((?- `Long`)
        *pi()/180))))*180/pi())*60*1.1515*1609.34)
        AS distance, Title, Description, posts.Pic as postPic, ReportID, DatePosted, posts.UserID as UserID, FName, SName, NotificationID as authorNotificationId, users.Pic as userPic,
        Lat, `Long`, photoWidth, photoHeight
        FROM posts
        INNER JOIN Users 
        ON Users.UserID = posts.UserID) foo
        WHERE distance <=? AND (Title LIKE ? OR Description LIKE ? OR FName LIKE ? OR SName LIKE ?) 
ORDER BY DatePosted DESC LIMIT ?, 10
```

Brief explanation of query: it tries to retrieve all posts within a user's pre-defined radius - by checking the distance between the coordinates of the user's registered location and the associated coordinates of a post (and checking that that distance is less than the user's registered radius)

Running explain gives me the following:

```
id             : 1
select_type    : Primary
table          : <derived2>
type           : **ALL**
possible_keys  : NULL
key            : NULL
key_len        : NULL
ref            : NULL
rows           : 824
Extra          : Using where; **Using filesort**

id             : 2
select_type    : DERIVED
table          : tableposts
type           : ALL
possible_keys  : NULL
key            : NULL
key_len        : NULL
ref            : NULL
rows           : 824
Extra          : NULL

id             : 2
select_type    : DERIVED
table          : Users
type           : eq_ref
possible_keys  : PRIMARY
key            : PRIMARY
key_len        : 4
ref            : db.posts.UserID
rows           : 1
Extra          : NULL
```

Is it the case that I only need to worry about query 1 and 2 due to the **ALL** select_type and the **filesort** in the extra.

Would I have to add an index to the column title and description? I already have an index on fname and sname in the users table.

As Olli pointed out, distance is a result of a calculation so I can't add an index to that

**UPDATE**

From Olli's answer, I get the following from EXPLAIN:

```
id           : 1
select_type  : SIMPLE
table        : posts
type         : ALL
possible_keys: postsUserID_idx
key          : NULL
key_len      : NULL
ref          : NULL
rows         : 825
Extra        : Using where; Using filesort

id           : 1
select_type  : SIMPLE
table        : Users
type         : eq_ref
possible_keys: PRIMARY
key          : PRIMARY
key_len      : 4
ref          : db.posts.UserID
rows         : 1
Extra        : Using where
```

**Update 2:**

Initial attempt for table restructure to add another col of type point as per symcbean's suggestion:

```
set @lat= 53.277656872106;
set @lon = -9.01179972749435;
set @dist = CONV_MI_KM(50000, 'k')/1000;
set @rlon1 = @lon-@dist/abs(cos(radians(@lat))*69);
set @rlon2 = @lon+@dist/abs(cos(radians(@lat))*69);
set @rlat1 = @lat-(@dist/69);
set @rlat2 = @lat+(@dist/69);

//set @geoCol = astext(envelope(linestring(point(@rlon1, @rlat1), point(@rlon2, @rlat2))));
set @geoCol = astext(linestring(point(@rlon1, @rlat1), point(@rlon2, @rlat2)));
set @geoCol2 = linestring(point(@rlon1, @rlat1), point(@rlon2, @rlat2));
```

I need to change my register prepared statement from:

```
INSERT INTO users VALUES 
    ('', ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, 0, ?, ?, 0, ?, 0)
```

to include the newCol at the end of the table after 0. Should this be what I've defined as geoCol2? The reason for the uncertainty is when binding the param in php I think I may need to use "s" as the bind type, as when looking up the types of params that can be bound to a statement, I only see s, i, d and b as options. Or am I off the mark?

Comment: when i see it right, your column distance is the result of a calculation? If so i can't see a way to actually add an index to that.

Comment: @Olli sorry yes you're right. Any other optimisation suggestion?

Comment: Is there any reason for that subselect? Did you try to write the whole query simply with joins (without the subselect)?

Comment: Use geospatial indexing to get the results in a bounding box, then if you really need a radius, do the trig on the resultset.

Comment: @Olli i wrote it months ago but I remember it was the only way I could get it working at the time! I kept getting errors, i can't remember the specifics but the subquery was necessary as far I could manage but maybe I don't need it??

Comment: @symcbean where would I even begin to work out a geospatial solution pertaining to my query above. Do I need to add new tables to my DB? I had a look and am very confused so far

Comment: Do you have an index on the DatePosted column?

Comment: @user2363025: Google is always a good place to start ;). You just need to add a single column (of type point) to represent the coordinates. e.g. https://www.percona.com/blog/2013/10/21/using-the-new-spatial-functions-in-mysql-5-6-for-geo-enabled-applications/

Comment: @Olli I do have an index on DatePosted yes

Comment: `OR` is a performance killer.  `WHERE` across two tables is a performance killer.  "Find nearest" without a bounding box is a performance killer.  Pagination via `OFFSET` is a performance killer.  [_My lat/lng blog_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/latlng) provides some of the answers.

Comment: @symcbean so what would I be storing in the extra column of type point? At present, I have a lat col, a long col, and a radius col. Would I need to do an on the fly calculation when registering that takes the user's long, lat and radius and using some function, stores a point value in a new col to which I add a spatial index? I'm just not sure which function I should be using for my desired outcome? Would it be geoFromText together with a polygon? I'm not sure how I would go about creating a circular polygon with a centre point and radius? I really appreciate the advice

Comment: Then please READ the comments and links. "how I would go about creating a circular polygon" - as per my comment earlier, use a BOUNDING BOX to get an approximate list for which you work out the distance.

Comment: @symcbean sorry I am trying my best here, I clicked the links as I mentioned geo functions I had looked up. There's just a lot of new info at once. Apologies I'm not very quick off the mark. I updated the q to show what I've attempted so far, I'm not sure if the envelope as text is what I should be inserting as the new extra col or if i should be using as box for the insert?

Answer (score 0):

Are you calculating the distance in miles or kilometers?

Could you please try this query (should be the same, only without subquery):

```
SELECT 
  (((acos(sin((?*pi()/180)) 
    * sin((`Lat`*pi()/180))+cos((?*pi()/180))
    * cos((`Lat`*pi()/180)) * cos(((?- `Long`)
    *pi()/180))))*180/pi())*111189.3006) AS distance,
  ReportID, 
  Title, 
  Description, 
  postPic , 
  DatePosted, 
  UserID, 
  FName, 
  SName, 
  authorNotificationId, 
  userPic,  
  Lat, 
  `Long`, 
  photoWidth, 
  photoHeight 
FROM
  posts 
JOIN Users ON (Users.UserID = posts.UserID) 
WHERE (Title LIKE ? OR Description LIKE ? OR FName LIKE ? OR SName LIKE ?) 
HAVING distance <= ?
ORDER BY 
  DatePosted DESC LIMIT ?, 10
```

Since you calculate the distance on the fly, you need the HAVING clause for your check, otherwise with WHERE it would fail with unknown column.

You can probably add the execution plan for this one as well?

Comment: thank you so much for simplifying the query! The execution time has went down from 0.0177 to 0.0020 with your having approach :) However, When i run the explain on your query, it still has a select type of ALL  and uses filesort on the first query. I'll add the explain results in an update

Comment: sorry I skipped over that! The radius val I'm comparing distance to in the having condition is stored in metres so the param passed in there is anything from 0 to 50000

Comment: cool, at least something.. still the question: Is your distance in km or miles? you could limit the searchable posts by defining a range for your lat/lon values, where you could also use indexes on those columns. This would reduce the number of rows to actually being calculated. But to be honest.. the time for your query is really good, so i wouldn't worry to much about the filesort... ;-)

Comment: its in metres not km or miles :) thanks for your help. Yeah I don't think filesort is much of an issue but it's the all that worries me. The time is good for now as there isn't a huge amount of rows but if the table gets really big then I'd be worried. When you say define a range for my lat long values, what do you mean exactly? Add a new column? and put and then put an index on that column?

Comment: hi again, there is no rush at all, (as I won't be implementing for a couple of weeks), but if you do get a chance and are willing, it would be great if you could look at the updated question and see if I am going along the right lines to try and implement a solution which would allow me to use geo spatial indexing and bounding boxes.